# Tap gesture with finger movement

Tags: ios, swift, event-handling, uitapgesturerecognizer

As far as i observed, Tap gestures cancels event when finger moves. Here a screenShot from Event Handling Guide:

[image]

I have already done some tests with the following code. Nope, it cancels...

[image: http://i.hizliresim.com/ogZVjR.png]

```
    @IBAction func dosomething(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
         //called by gesture recognizer   
        }
        @IBOutlet var red: UIView!
        @IBOutlet var green: UIView!

        @IBOutlet var yellow: UIView!

        @IBOutlet var white: UIView!

        //setting delegate when outlet get set.
        @IBOutlet var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer! { didSet { outlet.delegate = self
            }}
        //delegate func shouldReceiveTouch
        func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
            if touch.view == red {
                println("ez")
                return true
            }else if touch.view == green{
                println("bp")
                return false
            }else { view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
                return true}
        }
```

So if I'm right,  when `touchesMoved:` called, `tapGestureRecognizer` must have failed, but according to figure it does not. What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

When a user taps or drags their finger across a screen in an iPhone application, two things happen:

1. The view receives a `UITouch` object(s)
2. A `UIGestureRecognizer` may grab the `UITouch` object(s) and try to infer what the user is doing (pan in/out, scroll up/down, swipe between pages in a browser, etc.)

A `UIGestureRecognizer` will not know what the user is doing unless the user has finished tapping the screen. The iPhone will know when the user is done when the `UITouch` object(s) are no longer apart of the current view.

The thing is, `UIGestureRecognizer` doesn't "fail", but rather it has no value or meaning *until* the user's touches are "cancelled" or not apart of the view. This can be seen by the fourth column to the right of Figure 1-6. Another problem is that a tap is not what you think it is. It's just a single touch. The touch ends as soon as it begins. If you're trying to swipe or drag something across a screen, you need a different `UIGestureRecognizer` object such as `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, etc.

If you want to see this in action, try doing the following in an iOS Single View Application:

1. Make a `ViewController.swift` file.
2. Class your `ViewController` as a subclass of `UIViewController`.
3. Add a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol.
4. Add some `UITapGestureRecognizer` objects and `UITouch` objects and link them to a single view in your storyboard.
5. Set the `UIGestureRecognizer` object's `delegate` to the `UIViewController` or `self`.
6. Check when a touch begins and ends by adding some `println` statements in the `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `touchesEnded:withEvent`, and `touchesCancelled:withEvent` methods.

You can learn more about how these methods work in the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html) directly.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I think what you say is correct for general UIGestureRecognizer object. But when it comes to UITapGestureRecognizer, it seems that when i moved my finger, tapGesture become cancelled. I have already made some tests before asking question. Still not clear for me :|

Comment: I made an edit to my answer right before the paragraph where I listed out the things you should try out. The main idea is that your tapGesture only takes in tap-like behavior. You can't simply hold a tap and expect it not to cancel. You'll need another kind of UIGestureRecognizer object that will allow the user to hold a tap and/or drag it across the screen.

Comment: I have edited my question with the things i tried. I agree with all you have written so far. Im not trying to implement some code on purpose. Im just following the guide. Here it seems Apple chair man made a mistake by writing " tapGestureRecognizer " to table instead of " GestureRecognizer "

Comment: By the way, useful answer.